# Login Activity transition

Tags: android, parse-platform, authentication

Hi i have a login activity and a main activity, and i want to the app start with the main activity when the user its already logged in, i found a way but the issue is that when I open the app and the user is already logged in, the app open the login screen  and make a fast transition to the main activity ,  how do i eliminate that transition and the app open just the main activity, here its my code:

```
ParseUser usuario= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if(usuario!=null){
            Intent intento = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawerPrincipal.class);
            intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intento);

        }
```

Comment: Is this piece of code in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Take on SpalshscreenActivity always launch when app opens there you check is user loggedIn or not after that nevigate to MainActivity or LoginActivity. Most of the app do same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure CheckActivity is the starting ( LAUNCHER ) Activity. It will work.

```
public class CheckActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Check if there is current user info
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // Start an intent for the Main-Activity

        Intent intent = new Intent(CheckActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        // You can use intent flags ... I used just finish() function.
    } else {
        // Start an intent for the logged in activity

        startActivity(new Intent(CheckActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
        // You can use intent flags ... I used just finish() function.
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` right below `startActivity(intento);` This overrides the transition between changing activities.

Comment: thanks to all, actually i create an splash activity and its working great. best regards